# Using special characters in Velocity templates

Tags: velocity

I'm trying to use em dash (—) and multiplication symbol (×) in my Velocity template. But the output gives the following.

> â€” for em dash
>
> Ã— for multiplication symbol

I have added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` in the `<head/>` as well.

I tried using the following as well.

```
#set( $multiplySymbol = '×' )
```

But it gives the same output.

How to use these kind of special characters on Velocity?

Comment: Have you checked this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543015/escaping-special-characters-in-velocity-template

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151572/velocity-templates-seem-to-fail-with-utf-8

Comment: @user7294900 That helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following when getting the template vm file.

```
Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("template.vm", "UTF-8");
```

Thanks @user7294900